# Download png with curl not readable

Tags: curl, png

I want to download the following PNG file:

https://spartacus-idh.com/liseuse/978-2-36693-030-6/lect/ImGp6.png

However, when I type:

```
 curl -O https://spartacus-idh.com/liseuse/978-2-36693-030-6/lect/ImGp6.png
```

The resulting file can not be opened.

Can someone explain to me why this does not work?

Comment: It's totally readable. Go ahead, read it. `less ImGp6.png`. You might be surprised at how readable it is. :P Hint: The server won't let you download that file; it might be because you are IP-blocked, or Agent-blocked, or (most likely) it requires the referrer to be on its own domain, to prevent [hotlinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking).

Comment: Indeed an informative read :D But why is that? Why can't I make the same request with curl as I can with a browser where opening the link does not pose any problems?

Comment: Well, you're definitely not IP-blocked; but you still could be agent-blocked or referrer-blocked. If using Chrome, try to open Developer Tools, Network tab; load the page where you found the image, then in the Network tab find that line, right-click on it and Copy -> Copy as cURL. This should replicate the browser's request, and thus should work; then you can start removing different options to see which option is the one that the server keeps blocking you on. However, also note that this is grey hat ish.